# selecting values above x gives wrong results from matrix table. Can someone explain why?

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am using the Shapiro-Wilk test to test a set of data for normality. My problem is not in using the test but in generating a results table to identify the rows of results where the p-value is greater than 0.05.
To illustrate my question, I am using the golub dataset which gives a series of gene expression values from "ALL" and "AML" patients.

What I have done is as follows:

```
library (multtest)
data (golub)
gol.fac <- factor(golub.cl,levels=0:1, labels= c("ALL","AML"))

# the golub dataset has the expression values for 3051 genes so I've decided to use only the first 10 genes from the dataset to make it easier to work with
ALL10 <- golub[1:10, gol.fac=="ALL"]

# calculate Shapiro-Wilk test for normality
sh10 <- apply (ALL10, 1, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value)

# get the names of the first 10 genes from the golub.gnames matrix
ALL10names <- golub.gnames[1:10,2]

# combine gene names with normality p-value scores 
list10 <- cbind(ALL10names,sh10)

# find those that have normal distribution
normdist<- list10[,2]>0.05

# print a list of those with normal distribution
list10[which(normdist),]
```

the result I get is:

```
              ALL10names                                sh10                  
[1,] "AFFX-HUMISGF3A/M97935_MA_at (endogenous control)" "2.97359627770755e-07"
[2,] "AFFX-HUMISGF3A/M97935_3_at (endogenous control)"  "0.299103621399385"   
[3,] "AFFX-HUMGAPDH/M33197_5_at (endogenous control)"   "6.60564216346286e-07"
[4,] "AFFX-HUMGAPDH/M33197_M_at (endogenous control)"   "6.81945800629973e-07"
[5,] "AFFX-HSAC07/X00351_5_at (endogenous control)"     "3.3088559810058e-06" 
[6,] "AFFX-HSAC07/X00351_M_at (endogenous control)"     "1.30227973255158e-08"
```

As you can see, this is wrong! there are several values that are actually < 0.05 and only one which is actually >0.05 (which is what I want)

If I do:

```
which(normdist)
[1]  1  3  7  8  9 10
```

but

```
which (sh10 > 0.05)
[1] 3
```

so obviously the error occured at

```
normdist<- list10[,2]>0.05
```

My question is why did this happen? I want everything whose value is >0.05 in column 2 of list10...it looks right but yet I am getting a wrong result. As I said, I am learning R and so I want to understand what went wrong so I don't repeat my mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `cbind(ALL10names,sh10)` creates a matrix and coerces everything to a character.

Create a `data.frame` instead (columns can have different types)

```
list10 <- data.frame(ALL10names,sh10)
```

and everything will work as you want

Comment: Actually @mnel, at first, I wrote 'list10 <- as.data.frame(cbind(ALL10names,sh10))' but when I did 'which (list10[,2]>0.05)', I got the error message     'integer(0)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(list10[, 2], 0.05) : > not meaningful for factors
'. That is why I ended up just using    'cbind(ALL10names,sh10)' and did not use the data.frame function. I thought I had to use cbind to combine both vectors but from your example it seems I did not but yet, I have seen examples where someone has used data.frame and cbind together, that is 'as.data.frame(cbind())'. Can you explain why it didn't work?

Comment: The problem with `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` in your case is that it was coercing a character matrix (the results of `cbind`), and the character variables become factors (both columns). You would need to do something like `cbind(data.frame(ALL10names), sh10)`. An array (matrix) must have all elements the same type, and will default to character if any are character.

Comment: Thanks once again @mnel I understand now. I didn't quite know the subtle difference between a factor and character data type before but this has also helped me to get a grasp of this nuance. Thanks!!